# Fortran DLL in vb6:error about "character" and "read sentence"

Tags: dll, vb6, fortran, character

When trying to send a character to DLL,it seems not to be right(shown in "result_20170207").
Below is code about DLL:

```
subroutine char_1( pfilename )
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES stdcall,DLLEXPORT::char_1
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:"char_1"::char_1
!DEC$ ATTRIBUTES reference :: pfilename

character(len=512)::pfilename
!integer::i     !(about ERROR TWO )
write(*,*)trim(pfilename)
!read(*,*)i     !(about ERROR TWO )
open(unit=18,file="result_20170207",status='replace',action='write')
  write(18,*)"This is dll"
  write(18,*)trim(pfilename)
  write(18,*)"the third line"
close(18)
end subroutine
```

Below is code in vb6.0:

```
Private Declare Sub char_1 Lib "D:\try_vb\char_1\char_1_dll\char_1_dll\Debug\char_1_dll.dll" (ByVal char As String)

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim char As String
  char = "c:/desktop/aaa.txt"
  Text1.Text = char
  Call char_1(char)
End Sub

Private Sub Command2_Click()
  End
End Sub
```

ERROR ONE:
The error happened in the result file is:
[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJmBY.jpg)

I think it is because of the character.Why does it happen and how can i fix it? Thank you!

ERROR TWO:
By the way,when I add the code "read(*,*)i",another error is met.Shown below:
[severe(39)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uu5Lj.jpg)
Codes I add are shown in the code which are commented out:
I am puzzled about the two problems.

According to MarkJ's answer,I have change my DLL code like below(ERROR ONE ; code in "String_Functions module" is omitted here):

```
subroutine char_1( pfilename )
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES stdcall,DLLEXPORT::char_1
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES ALIAS:"char_1"::char_1
  !DEC$ ATTRIBUTES reference :: pfilename

  use String_Functions     !--------here--------!

  character(len=512)::pfilename
  character(len=512)::filename
  integer::ii      
  ii=Clen(pfilename)      !--------here--------!
  filename=Ctrim(pfilename)     !--------here--------!
  open(unit=18,file="result_20170207",status='replace',action='write')
    write(18,*)"This is dll"
    write(18,*)filename(1:ii)      !--------here--------!
    write(18,*)"the third line"
  close(18)

end subroutine
```

Comment: I don't understand your pictures. What do they show? Do you have some error messages which you can show as text?

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear.Below are some more explanations:

Comment: I click the "Enter" and the comment was submitted. So I add the remaining below:  (1) ERROR ONE: it is not an "error",because it can terminate normally. But the result file "result_20170207" does not store the correct character (i.e. line 2 in result file is giberish). Why does the line 2 cannot store correctly(like line 1 "This is DLL" and line 3 "the third line")?         (2) ERROR TWO: it is an error, and it is  a run-time eroor,so all error message is the picture "severe(39)", which indicates line 11 "read(*,*)i" is wrong. I was wondering why this sentence could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your error (1) VB6 is [sending a null-terminated string](http://www.lacan.upc.edu/doc/intel/compiler_f/main_for/bldaps_for/common/bldaps_hndl_charstr.htm). The string contains an ASCII zero character which indicates the end of the string. Fortran `TRIM` is not sufficient to remove this character. Try the `CTRIM` routine below.

```
! ------------------------
PURE INTEGER FUNCTION Clen_trim(s) ! returns same result as LEN_TRIM unless:
CHARACTER(*),INTENT(IN) :: s       ! last char non-blank is null, if true:
INTEGER :: i                       ! then len of C string is returned, note:
                                   ! Ctrim is only user of this function
i = INDEX(s, CHAR(0)) 
IF ( i == 0 ) i = LEN_TRIM(s)
Clen_trim = i

END FUNCTION Clen_trim

! ----------------
FUNCTION Ctrim(s1)  RESULT(s2)     ! returns same result as TRIM unless:
CHARACTER(*),INTENT(IN)  :: s1     ! last non-blank char is null in which
CHARACTER(Clen_trim(s1)) :: s2     ! case trailing blanks prior to null
s2 = s1                            ! are output
END FUNCTION Ctrim
```

Comment: Thx! But it seems not run well. I add the "MODULE String_Functions" in DLL,code is listed below:`subroutine char_1( pfilename )
......
use String_Functions
  character(len=512)::pfilename
  character(len=512)::filename
  integer::ii
  ii=Clen(pfilename)
  filename=Ctrim(pfilename)
  open(unit=18,file="result_20170207",status='replace',action='write')
    write(18,*)"This is dll"
    write(18,*)filename(1:ii)
    write(18,*)"the third line"
  close(18)
end subroutine`         The result file "line 2" is still giberish. Waiting for your answer.   ^_^